# awk seen duplicate first field of each column

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to perform addition of two columns on matching first field as a key with a awk command.
The file can contain 32 columns and more.
The Column "time" is fix.

Ex with 6 columns HDDx-U00:

```
    time,HDD0-U00,HDD1-U00,HDD2-U00,HDD0-U00,HDD1-U00,HDD2-U00
    2015/10/26 16:10,1,3,5,2,4,6
    2015/10/26 16:11,1,2,3,4,5,5
    2015/10/26 16:12,2,2,3,6,2,3
  ... more row  in the file...
```

Calculations:
row: 2015/10/26 16:10:

**HDD0-U00** as 1st key: (1+2)

**HDD1-U00** as 2nd  key:(3+4)

**HDD3-U00** as 3th  key: (5+6)

Finally,to have this result:

```
time,HDD0-U00,HDD1-U00,HDD2-U00
2015/10/26 16:10,3,7,11
2015/10/26 16:11,5,7,8
2015/10/26 16:12,8,4,6
```

I tried this with awk:

```
awk -F, '{k=$3;seen[k];for(i=4;i<=NF;++i)sum[k,i]+=$i}' $file
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure where do 2, 6, 10 come from based on 1,3,5,1,3,5. Better explain your logic.

Comment: make a simplified example, input/output. without those `...` since we don't know if the column number would be reduced too...

Comment: @fedorqui: 1+1 = 2, 3+3 = 6, 5+5 = 10; based on the repeating header fileds..(HDD0-U00 etc...)

Comment: So please Indi59 post a stand alone example together with a proper explanation, like @Kent suggested. We don't want to post an answer that then gets invalidated by a further explanation of what these `...` mean.

Comment: I give more explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
"No.","time",HDD0-U00,HDD1-U00,HDD2-U00,HDD0-U00,HDD1-U00,HDD2-U00
1,"2015/10/26 16:10",1,3,5,1,3,5
2,"2015/10/26 16:11",1,3,3,1,3,5
3,"2015/10/26 16:12",1,3,5,1,3,5
4,"2015/10/26 16:13",1,3,5,1,3,5
5,"2015/10/26 16:14",1,3,5,1,3,5

$ awk '
    # Split $1, $2, $NF on ","
    BEGIN {
        FS=",";
    }
    # Read first line to understand the header
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            head[i] = $i
        }
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            sum[head[i]] = $i;
        }
        # Print header:
        printf("%s", sum[head[1]]);
        for(i=2; i <= length(sum); i++) {
            printf(",%s", sum[head[i]]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        # Skip the last part of the script:
        next;
    }
    # Read all other lines
    {
        printf("%s,%s", $1, $2);
        # Remember to clear sum for every line
        delete sum;
        # Add up all of the values
        for (i=3; i <= NF; i++){
            sum[head[i]] += $i;
        }
        for(i=1; i <= length(sum); i++) {
            printf(",%s", sum[head[i+2]]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
' file
```

Comment: Really nice solution!

Comment: @Indi59 I think this solution might be dependent on gawk, because i use `length(arr)`

Answer (score 1):

If your shift pattern is *constant*:

```
awk -F\, -v shift=3 ' NR>1{printf("%s,%s",$1,$2)
          for (i=shift;i<=(NF/shift)+shift;i++){printf(",%s",$i+$(i+shift))};print ""}' file
```

**NOTE**: this will **not** take care of the `header`

Results:

```
1,"2015/10/26 16:10",2,6,10
2,"2015/10/26 16:11",2,6,10
3,"2015/10/26 16:12",2,6,10
4,"2015/10/26 16:13",2,6,10
5,"2015/10/26 16:14",2,6,10
```

Comment: no constant value. the header contain:HDD0-U00,...to...,HDD31-U00